# Convert Hive lateral view/explode on MAP to Cascading framework

Tags: hadoop, hive, cascading

I have a Hive query that explodes a map structure to check for a specific value in the value of the key-value pair. Is it possible to do this in Cascading?

The query is:

```
SELECT entry_id, entry_key
FROM entries
LATERAL VIEW explode( values ) values_explode AS user_id, user_map
WHERE user_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

And the table schema for **entries** is:

```
entry_id::string

entry_key::string

values::map[bigint, array[bigint]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the same in cascading using functons.

```
`public class CascadingExplode extends BaseOperation<Void> implements Function<Void> {
     public CascadingExplode(Fields fields) {
        super(fields);
     }
    @Override
    public void operate(FlowProcess flowProcess, FunctionCall<Void> functionCall) {
        List<Tuple> tuples = (Tuple)functionCall.getArguments().getObject("values");
        Tuple explodedT=new Tuple();
        explodedT.add(tuples.getInteger("field_name"));
        ...
        ...
        functionCall.getOutputCollector().add(explodedT);
}`
```